# in org-mode, how to specify different export options for LaTeX and HTML?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

In org-mode, I'd like to specify different export options for different export types, i.e. numbered headings and a table of contents for exporting to LaTeX/PDF, no numbering and no table of contents for exporting to HTML.

Is it possible to do this without having to manually edit the export options every time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `ox.el` (the Generic Export Engine for Org Mode) there is a filter system:

> Filters allow end-users to tweak easily the transcoded output. They are the functional counterpart of hooks, as every filter in a set is applied to the return value of the previous one.

One of the filters is `:filter-options`:

```
`:filter-options' applies to the property list containing export
options.  Unlike to other filters, functions in this list accept
two arguments instead of three: the property list containing
export options and the back-end.  Users can set its value through
`org-export-filter-options-functions' variable.
```

That means you can define a function similar to this one:

```lisp
(defun my-org-export-change-options (plist backend)
  (cond 
    ((equal backend 'html)
     (plist-put plist :with-toc nil)
     (plist-put plist :section-numbers nil))
    ((equal backend 'latex)
     (plist-put plist :with-toc t)
     (plist-put plist :section-numbers t)))
  plist)
```

And add this to the export filter:

```
(add-to-list 'org-export-filter-options-functions 'my-org-export-change-options)
```

The function will be called by the export and depending on the backend it will enable or disable the toc/section-numbers.

Comment: I don't think I understand fully. I added the above to my .emacs and I get `Lisp error: (void-function pcase)
  (pcase backend (\`html (plist-put plist :with-toc nil) (plist-put plist :section-numbers nil)) (\`latex (plist-put plist :with-toc t) (plist-put plist :section-numbers t)))
  my-org-export-change-options((:export-options nil :input-file `

Comment: The `pcase` function has been added in [Emacs 24.1](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/news/NEWS.24.1). I updated the answer so that it should work without `pcase`.

Please also note that my answer was tested with Org-mode version 8.2.4 (check with `M-x org-version`). Org-mode changed the exporting system with version 8.0. If you have Org-mode < 8.0 I think it would be best to upgrade your Org-mode, otherwise there might be more issues.